# MongoDB stuck on save

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a node js project where I'm trying to register a user. Pretty straight forward. I have my user model and endpoints set up.

I can see my request is reaching my register endpoint, but it seems things are getting stuck on the MongoDB side and the user never gets created. My requests usually fail because they take too long.

I've read previous posts and articles saying I should use the .connect function for mongoose. Still nothing.

I've whitelisted all my IPs, and granted admin access to my user so I know its not that.

I can see in my register function that the registerData and req.body are there because they are printed to the console. savedUser is not printed.

index.js - connection

```js
mongoose.connect(config.DB_URI, { useNewUrlParser: true })
  .then(() => console.log('DB Connected!'))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

user.js - controller register function

```
exports.register = function(req, res) {
  const registerData = req.body
  console.log(req.body);

  if (!registerData.email) {
    return res.status(422).json({
      errors: {
        email: 'is required',
        message: 'Email is required'
      }
    })
  }

  if (!registerData.password) {
    return res.status(422).json({
      errors: {
        password: 'is required',
        message: 'Password is required'
      }
    })
  }

  if (registerData.password !== registerData.passwordConfirmation) {
    return res.status(422).json({
      errors: {
        password: 'is not the same as confirmation password',
        message: 'Password is not the same as confirmation password'
      }
    })
  }

  const user = new User(registerData);
  console.log(registerData);
  return user.save((errors, savedUser) => {
    if (errors) {
      return res.status(422).json({errors})
    }

    console.log(savedUser);
    return res.json(savedUser)
  })
}
```

user.js - model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')
const config = require('../config/dev')

const userSchema = new Schema({
  email: { type: String,
           required: 'Email is Required',
           lowercase: true,
           unique: true,
           match: [/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/]},
  name: { type: String,
          required: false,
          min: [6, 'Too short, min is 6 characters']},
  password: {
    type: String,
    min: [4, 'Too short, min is 4 characters'],
    max: [32, 'Too long, max is 32 characters'],
    required: 'Password is required'
  },
  createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  updatedAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
});

userSchema.pre("save", function(next){
   const user = this;

   bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
      if(err){ return next(err);}

      bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, function(err, hash){
          if(err){ return next(err);}

          user.password = hash;
          next();
      });
   });
});

//Every user have acces to this methods
userSchema.methods.comparePassword = function(candidatePassword, callback){
   bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, this.password, function(err, isMatch){
      if(err) {return callback(err);}

      callback(null, isMatch);
   });
}


userSchema.methods.generateJWT = function () {
  return jwt.sign({
    email: this.email,
    id: this._id
  }, config.JWT_SECRET, {expiresIn: '1h'})
}

userSchema.methods.toAuthJSON = function () {
  return {
    _id: this._id,
    name: this.name,
    email: this.email,
    token: this.generateJWT()
  };
}

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema );
```

Users never actually get created the program gets stuck. I'd expect this to actually be able to save and not be stuck.

Comment: Try to debug the full process. Add `console.log(errors, savedUser)` in the first line of the `user.save`, before the `if (errors)`, and some more logs inside the pre-save middleware, before each function, to check if everything runs correctly. Let us know which is the last printed log

Comment: Are you sure you need `req.body` instead of `req.body.data`?

Comment: @VirgilioGM added logs as you say in before each step, and within each step along with what is already there. All of the logs for email and password checks pass (none of the longs inside those checks printed which is good). The last log is the "pre save" log which is right above the user.save method and right below the ```console.log(registerData)```. the ```console.log(errors, savedUser)``` never gets called

Comment: Did you added a console.log in the pre-save middleware just before calling `next()`? I'll bet this line is not being executed

Comment: @VirgilioGM yes the next() gets called. I put a console.log right before it in the pre-save middleware

Comment: @VirgilioGM what is interesting is that I put a console.log before return ```res.json(savedUser)``` and that never gets displayed and I have no clue how that could happen